# Nest Js: Webscoket Reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, websocket, graphql, nestjs

I created a graphql subscription server which runs on port 7777 with the path /subscriptions/graphql for both HTTP, WebSocket protocol which is absolutely working fine when I directly used the URL with other services.

```
HTTP : http://localhost:7777/subscriptions/graphql
websocket: ws://localhost:7777/subscriptions/graphql
```

Subscription server is a microservices just like the other services we have. Now my aim is to do a reverse proxy in the gateway. I wanted to do a reverse proxy for both HTTP, WebSocket based connections.

For this, I wrote two middleware one for HTTP and one for Websocket. Http based middleware is working fine. Whereas the WebSocket is not working as expected.

**Websocket based Middileware**

```
import { NestMiddleware, Logger, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware';

@Injectable()
export class SubscriptionServiceWebSocketReverseProxyMiddleware
  implements NestMiddleware {
  /*
  jscpd:ignore-start
  */
  constructor(private readonly logger: Logger) { }
  

  private proxy = createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'ws://localhost:7777/subscriptions/graphql',
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    ws: true,
    onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
      this.logger.debug(
        `[SubscriptionServiceWebSocketReverseProxyMiddleware]: Proxying ${req.method} request originally made to '${req.originalUrl}'...`,
      );
    },
  });

  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    this.proxy(req, res, next);
  }
  /*
  jscpd:ignore-end
  */
}
```

When the websocket request made  from UI, I am getting below error

```
[Nest] 43743   - 08/24/2020, 3:20:20 PM   [SubscriptionServiceWebSocketReverseProxyMiddleware]: Proxying GET request originally made to '/subscriptions/ws/graphql'...
[HPM] Upgrading to WebSocket
events.js:200
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:200:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

*Note: I was able to see the log message inside the middleware which means there is no issue with middleware. I also see the subscription service alone is working as well.*